# Proper way to read big file into char array

Tags: c++, file, input

I am using a code from `GeeksForGeeks` and I want to test it on big input files so I fiddled a bit with the code to allocate arrays dynamically.

I know that I get this error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc
>     what():  std::bad_alloc`

because I'm running out of memory, but I don't know the proper way to read a big file, for reference.

This is the code that I'm using

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<fstream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

// A utility function to find maximum of two integers
int max(int a, int b)
{   return (a > b)? a : b; }

/* Returns length of longest common substring of X[0..m-1]
   and Y[0..n-1] */
int LCSubStr(char *&X, char *&Y, int m, int n)
{

// Create a table to store lengths of longest common suffixes of
// substrings.   Notethat LCSuff[i][j] contains length of longest
// common suffix of X[0..i-1] and Y[0..j-1]. The first row and
// first column entries have no logical meaning, they are used only
// for simplicity of program
clock_t t;
t=clock();
int** LCSuff = new int*[m+1];
for(int i = 0; i < m+1; ++i)
    LCSuff[i] = new int[n+1];
int result = 0;  // To store length of the longest common substring

/* Following steps build LCSuff[m+1][n+1] in bottom up fashion. */
for (int i=0; i<=m; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<=n; j++)
    {
        if (i == 0 || j == 0)
            LCSuff[i][j] = 0;

        else if (X[i-1] == Y[j-1])
        {
            LCSuff[i][j] = LCSuff[i-1][j-1] + 1;
            result = max(result, LCSuff[i][j]);
        }
        else LCSuff[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

t = clock() - t;
printf("It took me %d clicks (%f seconds).\n",t,((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
cout<<"----------------------------"<<endl;
return result;
}

/* Driver program to test above function */
int main()
{
std::ifstream in("F1.txt");
std::string XS((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in)),
std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
std::ifstream inn("F2.txt");
std::string YS((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(inn)),
std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

char *X=new char[XS.length()];
char *Y=new char[YS.length()];

XS.copy( X, XS.length() );
YS.copy( Y, YS.length() );
int m = strlen(X);
int n = strlen(Y);

cout << "Length of Longest Common Substring is "
     << LCSubStr(X, Y, m, n)<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a memory mapped file.

Comment: Don't use code from GeeksForGeeks would seem to be the best advice.

Comment: If you are working with strings use a `std::string` instead of manually allocating space.  If it is binary data then `std::vector<char>`.

Comment: @NathanOliver:  A `std::vector<uint8_t>` would be a better choice for binary data because a `char` could be signed or unsigned or `char`.  Usually for binary data, all 8 bits are significant.

Comment: @NathanOliver I tried using vectors, I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading the full file into memory, you need to read it chunk by chunk. This implies that your algorithm needs to be rewritten in order to implement partial updates to its state.

In your case, since your accesses to `X` and `Y` are sequential, you can do so without significant changes in how the algorithm works.

In pseudocode:

```
state = lcs_init();

for (;;) {
    chunk = read();
    if (eof)
        break;

    state = lcs_update(state, chunk);
}

result = lcs_finish(state);
```

Typically, in C++ (and OOP in general), this is done using a class that stores the state, i.e.:

```
LCS lcs;
for (each chunk)
    lcs.update(chunk);
result = lcs.result();
```